# Menu do site não funciona em algumas página para dispositivos móveis

Tags: php, css, menu, include

Fiz um site onde o menu é inserido em todas as páginas através de um include. Acontece que em algumas páginas quando o menu fica no formato para dispositivos móveis funciona normalmente e em outras páginas ele não abre. O que pode estar ocorrendo? Achei estranho porque se o menu está vindo através de um include ele deveria se comportar igual para todas as páginas, não? Veja nos links a seguir um exemplo

Este funciona
https://www.gestaoderestaurantes.com.br/grconsult/index.php

Este não funciona 
https://www.gestaoderestaurantes.com.br/grconsult/tutorial.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara seu problema é que vc está chamando os `Scripts` da `Navbar` só na `Index.php` e não nas outras página. Então em **TODAS** as páginas que vc for usar essa `Navbar` vc tem que indexar esses `scripts`

**Isso é na INDEX.PHP**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> E olha na outra página, não tem os **.JS**
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Exatamente isto. Agora funcionou. Valeu demais.

Comment: @Alison se resolveu ai considere marcar a resposta como aceita nesse ícone abaixo das setinhas da minha resposta **`✔`** , assim ela não fica sem resposta aceita, mesmo já tendo resolvido